# React-bootstrap Datetimepicker issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm currently working on a Project and we need to use a date-time picker component for react. We are currently using this one:

https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker

But we had an issue with it, forked it and tried to solve our problem. Here's the link of my fork:

https://github.com/fertaku/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Our problem right now is... how can I integrate this react component fork into my rails application using npm?

I've already seen a couple tutorials around and I've tried them. 
They involved mainly using the repo URL in the package.json file and then executing npm install, but somehow it didn't work:

Error: Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap-datetimepicker'

Why the original version works with npm install but the fork doesn't? It looks like when I execute npm install with the fork url then the build is not complete or it just lack of some symbolic links or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"react-bootstrap-datetimepicker" repository is not maintained anymore and Depreciated, please refer to this fork : https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime

Answer (score 2):

As of today, you can also use this component which uses Bootstrap 4 styles: https://github.com/tonix-tuft/react-tempusdominus-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix the url with "github:" instead of "https:". It should look like this in your package.json

```
"react-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "github:fertaku/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker",
```